# Expressão regular para valor monetário

Tags: java, regex

Observem o código em Java:

```
String valor = 1.500,00;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(valor);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Valor validado - OK");
} else {
    System.out.println("Valor incorreto");
}
```

Eu preciso validar a String `valor`. Eu preciso que ela seja verdadeira, mas parece que a expressão regular `\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?` não está certa pois não está compatível com a estrutura **1.500,00**. Já tentei também dessa forma: `\\d{2}$`, mas não funciona.

Preciso de ajuda para acertar a expressão regular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é fazer:

```
String valor = "1.500,00"; // <-- faltou as aspas no seu código
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{3})*,\\d{2}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(valor);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Valor validado - OK");
} else {
    System.out.println("Valor incorreto");
}
```

A regex começa com `\\d{1,3}`: de 1 a 3 dígitos.

Depois temos `(\\.\\d{3})*`. Explicando de dentro para fora:

- `\\.` é um ponto propriamente dito (o ponto possui significado especial em regex - corresponde a [qualquer caractere](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) - e para que a regex considere somente o caractere `.`, é preciso escapá-lo com `\`)
- `\\d{3}` é "exatamente 3 dígitos"
- o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` indica "zero ou mais ocorrências" do que vem antes. No caso, o que tem antes é toda a sequência "ponto mais 3 dígitos" (agrupados entre parênteses)

Ou seja, a sequência "ponto seguido de 3 dígitos" pode se repetir várias vezes (assim podemos ter valores como "1.500,00", "1.500.000,00", etc), ou nenhuma (no caso de valores menores que 1000).

Depois temos a vírgula, seguida de dois dígitos.

O resultado do código acima é `"Valor validado - OK"`.

---

Se quiser, também pode usar:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{3})*,\\d{2}$");
```

Os marcadores `^` e `$` são, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Assim eu garanto que ela só tem o que está especificado na regex. Se eu não usá-los, a regex pode considerar válidas `Strings` que contém o número no meio do texto.

---

Apenas para explicar as regex que você tentou:

- `\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?`: esta regex é `\\d+` (um ou mais dígitos - ou seja, **qualquer** quantidade maior ou igual que 1), seguido de ponto e 1 ou 2 dígitos (`\\d{1,2}`), e esse último trecho depois do ponto é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (por causa do `?` logo depois do parênteses).
- `\\d{2}$`: esta regex só verifica se a string termina com 2 dígitos (não importa o que tem antes)