# Como ajustar a expressão regular no Java?

Tags: java, regex

Observem o código:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{3})*,\\d{2}$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dadosCSV[position4]);
```

E peguei essa expressão regular já pronta, ela é para validar valores assim: **1.500,00**.

Mas agora preciso validar valores assim: **1500,00**.

Como ficaria a expressão regular?

Eu tentei dessa forma:

```
^\\d{1,3}(\\\\d{3})*,\\d{2}$
```

Mas não deu certo.

Comment: O entendeu o que cada pedaço da regex faz?

Comment: @wladyband, a minha resposta abaixo resolveu o problema? Caso tenha faltado alguma coisa, é só avisar que eu a atualizo :-)

Answer (score 1):

Se você só quer validar o formato "vários dígitos, vírgula, dois dígitos", basta usar:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d+,\\d{2}$");
```

O [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", então `\\d+` é "um ou mais dígitos", que é exatamente o que tem antes da vírgula. (Lembrando que em uma `String` Java, cada `\\` se torna um único caractere `\`, por isso o `\\d` da `String` corresponde a regex `\d`, que é o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para dígitos de 0 a 9).

---

Na sua regex tem `\\\\d{3}`. Como está em uma `String`, cada `\\` é traduzido para um único caractere `\`. Então esta `String` na verdade corresponde à regex `\\d{3}`, que quer dizer "o caractere `\`, seguido de 3 letras `d`".

E como antes temos `\\d{1,3}` (de 1 a 3 dígitos), a sua regex procura por 1 a 3 dígitos, seguido opcionalmente de `\` + 3 letras `d` (podendo se repetir várias vezes), seguido de vírgula e 2 dígitos. Como "1500,00" tem 4 dígitos antes da vírgula, o primeiro trecho não é suficiente para pegar todos os dígitos até a vírgula (e a parte que tem `\` e 3 letras `d` não encontra nenhuma correspondência também). Por isso não funciona.

Curiosamente, a sua regex funciona para valores menores que 1000 (como "10,00", por exemplo), já que possui de 1 a 3 dígitos antes da vírgula (e a parte entre parênteses é opcional, pois pode se repetir de zero a várias vezes). [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/ls9YFf/1/) um exemplo da sua regex, e [veja a diferença para a minha](https://regex101.com/r/93j3G4/2/).

---

Este trecho entre parênteses (`\\.\\d{3}`) era necessário para validar um ponto a cada 3 dígitos (conforme explicado em detalhes na [sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/388903/112052)). Mas agora que não tem mais pontos, podemos simplesmente verificar se tem um ou mais dígitos antes da vírgula.

Se quiser, você pode ajustar a quantidade de dígitos, conforme sua necessidade. Exemplo:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{2,10},\\d{2}$");
```

No caso, `{2,10}` vai aceitar entre 2 e 10 dígitos antes da vírgula.

Também poderia ser `{2,}` para aceitar no mínimo 2 dígitos, sem limite máximo. Ajuste os valores conforme o que você precisar.