# Regex passa no teste do site mas no código não funciona

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Criei um regex ( ^\d{1,}(.\d{2})?$ ) que era para permitir valores no formato 21 ou 21.30. Testei a regex num site e funcionou:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo o seguinte código:

```
const regexMoneyFormat = RegExp('^\d{1,}(\.\d{2})?$');
    console.log('valor convertido pra string', price.toString())
    if (!regexMoneyFormat.test(price.toString())) {
      console.log('resultado do teste', regexMoneyFormat.test(price.toString()))
      throw new AppError('Price format invalid, valid shapes: 0 ou 0.00');
    }
```

Só que os valores no formato que falei, como o valor 1 ou o valor 60.21 não estão passando. Pelo print vi que a função toString() está convertendo corretamente, mas não tá passando pela regex.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que no código não está funcionando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O construtor de `RegExp` recebe uma string, e em strings o caractere `\` deve ser escapado com outra `\`, ficando `\\`. Ou seja, deveria ser assim:

```
const regexMoneyFormat = RegExp('^\\d+(\\.\\d{2})?$');
```

Outro detalhe é que troquei o quantificador `{1,}` por `+` já que ambos significam "uma ou mais ocorrências".

---

Se bem que você também pode usar a forma literal, delimitando a expressão entre barras:

```
const regexMoneyFormat = /^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/;
```

Assim não é necessário o escape e você pode usar apenas `\`.

---

Sobre regex para valores monetários, vale dar uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/388911/112052)  e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/342879/112052).

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/488607/69296) já pontuou, você deve escapar as barras invertidas em uma expressão regular construída a partir do construtor uma vez que essa é uma necessidade das próprias strings. E o construtor aceita strings.

Claro, daria para utilizar a forma literal (como já indicado):

```
const regex = /^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/;
```

Mas se você eventualmente precisar de utilizar o construtor e não quiser escapar a string (imagine uma *regex* que possua muitos caracteres que precisem ser escapados), uma opção é utilizar o [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw):

```
const regexStr = String.raw`^\d+(\.\d{2})?$`;
const regex = new RegExp(regexStr);
```

Ou, em única linha:

```
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`^\d+(\.\d{2})?$`);
```

O *tag* `String.raw`, para *template strings*, é extremamente útil em situações como essa, já que não processa sequências de escape.